# How to replace iPhone 4 front glass?

Tags: iphone, hardware

My iPhone 4 front glass broke. Screen is OK, I only want to replace the glass. Assuming I get a new glass, is it hard to replace it myself? Can anyone provide some step by step tutorial on how to replace it?

Comment: If you have an iPhone 4, then it is most likely still under warranty. Martin answered the question (and gets props for doing so), but I would argue to just take it in to be serviced by Apple. You risk a lot more than just voiding the warranty by doing this yourself.

Comment: Apple typically has a $299 replacement fee for phones that are extensively damaged. In the past, they waved this fee. I'm not sure how they would treat you should your phone be out of warranty. But replacing the glass alone using eBay is rife with  disappointment. Separating the digitizer from the screen is no trivial process. You'll also be the target of eBay's infamous bait and switch, where sellers promise genuine products but ship knock-offs. Remember that the Gorilla glass used in the iPhone 4 is of the highest quality. An inferior product will lead to insufferable results.

Answer (score 2):

As with every "do it yourself" and "Apple", you have to be careful and know that it will possibly **void your warranty**. In any case, if you still decide to proceed with this, it is certainly possible to replace your iPhone 4's glass. There's a very nice tutorial with pictures at iFixit.

[Installing iPhone 4 Front Panel Assembly](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repair/Installing-iPhone-4-Front-Panel-Assembly/3148/1)

> "Replacing the display assembly will
>   give you a new front glass panel,
>   digitizer, and LCD. The LCD is adhered
>   to the glass at the factory and the
>   two parts are not separable without
>   damage."

Comment: Just as a bit of advice, I replaced the glass on my 3GS a while back and while it was difficult, it was certainly doable. The only real problem I had is that the replacement glass didn't have Apple's oleophobic (oil resistant) coating. It didn't seem like it would be much of a problem, but it turned out to be *very* difficult to clean and just about impossible to keep clean. With the old glass I could just wipe it across my shirt a time or two, but with the replacement I had to wipe and wipe and wipe, even needing water to get stuff off.

Comment: "the two parts are not separable without damage" - that implies I would have to change the LCD in addition to the glass? However, I found only the glass for sale on Taobao. My guess is there should be some way to change just the glass, isn't it?

Comment: I'm sure the vender selling the glass would know better than Apple, so, sure, buy it from them. What do you have to lose?

Comment: Because of the way the iPhone 4 is designed, I haven't seen anyone selling just the glass. You have to buy an assembly with the display LCD integrated. Shame, isn't it?

Comment: @Greg: Apple is not the one who said "the two parts are not separable without damage"; it was iFixIt, who, sells only Glass + LCD + Digitizer assy's together. There is absolutely a way to replace the glass alone. However, if you just buy the glass itself off ebay, make sure the vendor supplies the digitizer adhesive. If not, you can buy it separately. You simply carefully separate the digitizer/LCD assy from the glass itself, then re-adhere them to the new glass using the digitizer adhesive.

Comment: This is what iFixit has to say: "The worst part about shattering the front glass on the iPhone 4 isn't the bleeding fingertips that come free with it, it's that you will also have to replace the LCD even if you didn't break it." I'd heed their warning and just by the entire assembly. They want $129 for a certified genuine Apple part that won't have you bent over a desk with a hair dryer trying not to destroy your LCD as pry it from the digitizer. A "no-brainer" in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't attempt to remove the glass from the LCD.  The 4 is NOTHING like the 3.  Just replace the whole thing and be done with it.  You can get a new LCD assembly for under $30, including shipping, from Amazon.